# Saving a symmetric SecKeyRef to OSX keychain

Tags: cocoa, keychain

I'm trying to create a symmetric encryption key using Security Transforms in OSX and then save that key to the keychain. I'm able to create a working key and save it to the keychain, but when I recall the key and try to use it, I get a CDSA error that "a missing value was detected".

Also pertinent. After I've saved the key to the keychain, if I try to delete it manually, I get an error that says "A missing value was detected" and if I try to create a second key with a different label, I'm told that the key already exists in the keychain.

Here's the code I'm using to save the SecKeyRef to the keychain, cobbled together from one of the Security Transforms examples. Would welcome any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong. Are there other required attributes for the SecKeychainAttributeList that I'm missing? Am I storing the key data itself incorrectly? I'm not so familiar with working in C.

```
+ (BOOL)addKey:(SecKeyRef)key withLabel:(NSString*)label
{
    OSStatus err;
    SecKeychainItemRef item = nil;

   const char *itemLabelUTF8 = [label UTF8String];

    SecKeychainAttribute attrs[] = {
        { kSecLabelItemAttr, strlen(itemLabelUTF8), (char *)itemLabelUTF8 }
    };

    SecKeychainAttributeList attributes = { sizeof(attrs) / sizeof(attrs[0]),
        attrs };

    err = SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(
                                       kSecSymmetricKeyItemClass,//class of item being     created
                                       &attributes,//attributes dictionary
                                       sizeof(key),//length of buffer holding data to store
                                       key, //buffer with data to store
                                       NULL, // use the default keychain
                                       NULL,//access object to define access. null = access for this app
                                       &item);//reference to created item on return

    if (item) CFRelease(item);

    if (err == errSecSuccess) {
        DDLogVerbose(@"created keychain item");
        return YES;
    } else if (err == errSecDuplicateItem){
        DDLogVerbose(@"key already exists in keychain");
        return NO;
    } else {
        DDLogVerbose(@"error: %d", err);
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem.
But generally you should use `SecItemAdd`, thats what Apple DevDocs are saying: [Apple DevDocs Keychain Service Tasks for OSX (at the end of the page)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH205-SW5).

I use to store a symmetric key the following code, wich in fact works, but deleting is still a mess. ;-)
Any suggestions are also for Me welcomed.
Hope it helps anyway:

```
// Identifier for symmetric key
static const uint8_t keyIdentfier[] = "this.is.my.TestKeyLabel";
NSData *tag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:keyIdentfier length:sizeof(keyIdentfier)];

// Simple keygen algo - JUST FOR EXAMPLE DO NOT USE!
NSMutableData *key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:8];
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 8, key.mutableBytes);
NSString *base64key = [key base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[dict setObject:tag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[dict setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[dict setObject:key forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

// Insert key into keychain based on dictionary attributes above
OSStatus osstatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict, NULL);
```